# Where can I see a list of supported bluetooth drivers?

Tags: 10.04, drivers, bluetooth

Where can I see a list of supported bluetooth drivers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluetooth is a bit special, all devices basically speak the same language. There are a few versions of the Bluetooth protocol, which is all that's needed for your Bluetooth device to work, so long as it's connected through an open protocol connector such as USB or PCI(e).

BlueZ, the Linux bluetooth stack, supports all of the core protocols and is regarded as a *qualified implementation* by the [Bluetooth Special Interest Group](https://www.bluetooth.org/).

There are *a few* drivers in the kernel, mostly related do devices' special firmware, which you can [browse here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/drivers/bluetooth/). This is indeed the full list of drivers, and it's very small.

As long as your device implements the Bluetooth specification properly, which most do, Linux will support it. If in your case something does't work correctly, consider asking a specific question or [filing a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).